# Using regex to match strings if they contain "MSIE" but NOT if they contain "Opera"

Tags: regex, user-agent

My ultimate aim is to use regex to match HTTP_USER_AGENT strings for IE 7 and lower PLUS Opera 9.0 and lower.

This is because these are the browsers that do not support the CSS "box-sizing"

Im not really an expert in regex syntax.

But i went through the "http user agent" list i found on google for [Opera](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Opera/) and [IE](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/)

```
(MSIE [2-7]\.+)|(rv:1\.8\.1\.1+)|(Opera/[4-8]\.+)|(Opera [4-8]\.+)|(Opera\/9\.00+)
```

This is the regex I use to match all the HTTP_USER_AGENTS in the said lists above. (I'm not sure if the list contains ALL possible user agents. Probably not)

But anyways, That regex matches them all. but it allso matches some newer versions of Opera

E.G.

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; X11; Linux i686; de) Opera 10.10
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 6.0; tr) Opera 10.10
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Linux i686 ; en) Opera 9.70
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; X11; Linux x86_64; en) Opera 9.60
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; ru) Opera 9.52
```

So Im one step away. The distinguishing factor is the ALL OPERA versions 9 PLUS that do contain "MSIE 6." ALSO contain "Opera " at the end.

So I need to modify my regex to match ALL "MSIE 6." strings that DO NOT contain "OPERA "

As I've said, the regex I currently have may not be the best. But hey, I'm new to regex!

Thanks

Alex

Comment: My usual advice in situations like this is to do two checks, since most of the time it isn't really critical to squeeze all the checking into a single regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to not match the MSIE values which are followed by `Opera`, eg:

```
MSIE [2-7]\.\d+(?!.*Opera)|Opera[ /](?:[4-8]\.\d+|9\.00)|Opera$
```